# L1 vs L2 or MSE vs MAE and euclidean norm.. Formulas are different? why use interchangeably?

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://www.facebook.com/groups/1738168866424224/?multi_permalinks=2387228081518296&notif_id=1566797456400242&notif_t=feedback_reaction_generic

I need some clarification about the loss function used in ML. We usually call MAE as L1 loss and MSE as L2 loss or Euclidean norm... (Formulas are mentioned in attached Image)

```
L1 = sum (|x(true_label) - x(prediction)|)
```

and

```
L2 = sum ((x(true_label) - x(prediction)^2)
```

Question # 1: But the confusion is, in MAE and MSE, we divide by total number of classes (n), but not in L1 and L2?

```
MAE = (sum (|x(true_label) - x(prediction)|))
```

and

```
MSE = (sum ((x(true_label) - x(prediction)^2))
```

Question # 2: L2 loss also called Euclidean norm. But in Euclidean norm we take the under root, bit in L2 we don't take under root.

Their formulas are different from each other. Kindly explain me, why their names are used interchangeably like L2 norm as (Euclidean Distance, the Mean Squared Error (MSE) / Least Squares Error, or the Ridge Operator)?

Comment: Your formulars for L1 and MAE differ only by an extra set of parantheses. Please clarify your question. Besides that, the mentioned division by `n` is just a linear scaling factor.

Comment: Anyway for new comers take a look into  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26180/l2-loss-vs-mean-squared-loss

Answer (score -1):

L1 and MAE as well as L2 and MSE are often used interchangeably by the community, but actually there is a slight different:

L1 is the sum of absolute errors, while MAE is the mean of the absolute error between a prediction and the ground truth. The mean is obtain by summing all n elements and divide by the number of elements n.

Similar, L2 is the sum of squared errors, while MSE is the mean of the squared errors.

The euclidean norm is the length of a vector and as you said has a square root in its equation.

To answer your question why they are used interchangeably: It is a mistake and I guess it is because due to their similarity people mix it up and they are used interchangeably in textbooks and tutorials so people learn it wrong and might not even be aware of it.

[image]